# dotnet build command for multiple projects of .NET standard, .NET Core and .NET Framework 4.6.1 in one solution gives error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, build, command-line-interface

My solution consists of multiple projects of .NET Standard, .NET Framework 4.6.1 and .NET Core 2.x. When I build my solution with dotnet build command on CLI gives errors.

.NET Standard and .NET Core projects build successfully but the .NET Framework 4.6.1 projects give errors.

Build command is `dotnet build D:\Projects\granite-gateway-api\src\Granite.Gateway.sln`

errors in build are:
`Build FAILED.

D:\Projects\granite-gateway-api\src\WebService\Granite.WebService.CallbackReceiver.TMobile\Granite.WebService.CallbackReceiver.TMobile.csproj(154,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3049,5): error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run. [D:\Projects\granite-gateway-api\src\WindowsService\Granite.WindowsService.CallbackSender\Granite.WindowsService.CallbackSender.csproj]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3049,5): error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run. [D:\Projects\granite-gateway-api\src\WindowsService\Granite.WindowsService.Adapter\Granite.WindowsService.Adapter.csproj]

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3049,5): error MSB4216: Could not run the "GenerateResource" task because MSBuild could not create or connect to a task host with runtime "CLR4" and architecture "x86".  Please ensure that (1) the requested runtime and/or architecture are available on the machine, and (2) that the required executable "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.507\MSBuild.exe" exists and can be run. [D:\Projects\granite-gateway-api\src\WindowsService\Granite.WindowsService.ResponseFetch\Granite.WindowsService.ResponseFetch.csproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    4 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:09.80
`

Comment: Could you add Build command and errors as code not immage?

Comment: Looks like this is know issue: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/8456
Try to follow workaround that provided in issue

Comment: In the error shown, it cannot find msbuild in path for sdk net core 2.1. you typed net core 2.2...is that correct?

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori Sorry there are multiple projects having different versions. I have edited my question.

Comment: @Lemm I have added build command and errors in code format. Please have a look.

Comment: In general .NET Framework projects require MSBuild. Please use MSBuild command line to compile the solution, not `dotnet build`.

Comment: if you build a single project, do you get the error?

Comment: @LexLi MSBUILD command also not working.

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori yes if i build single project I get same error

Comment: @IqraMunir no one project build successfully? not even net core or net standard prj?

Comment: @LexLi dotnet build uses MSBuild inside. At least that is written on MSDN https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build#msbuild

Comment: Does your .NET Framework 4.6.1 project is WPF, Windows Forms or other type of project that is NOT supported by .Net Core?

Comment: @LorenzoIsidori Other projects build successfully except the ones with .NET framework 4.6.1 projects.

Comment: @Lemm yes it is a web service in .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: @Lemm That's incorrect. Using MSBuild inside, does not mean that dotnet build behaves the same way. There are significant amount of differences under the hood.